# FaunaDB, make connection between different users, I.e. become friends

Tags: reactjs, next.js, faunadb

I have a use case where I want to connect two different user roles, and if they accept and want to connect, new features will open up. It is very similar to how friend requests work at Facebook or LinkedIn, opening up and showing more content. Let's call them `role1` and `role2`.

All users are stored within a "users" collection with an `id`. Depending on their provided role within the document attached to the "users" collection, they can store additional data in their respective role-collection, i.e., `role1` collection or `role2` collection.

What is the best approach and structure to connect the two users, i.e., become "friends"? Should I have the connection stored in a new collection, named perhaps `connections`-collection, or multiple collections?

I'm using Next.js, NextAuth for user authentication, and FaunaDB as a database. I'm using Fauna's query language, FQL.

Comment: When you say "connect two different user roles", do you mean users, roles, or both? What does "connection" mean? Just the "I'm connected to x" from both perspectives? Many-to-many relationships are typically modelled with a "join table", which in Fauna would typically mean a document in a separate collection. Roles and collections are different things in Fauna, so what is a "role collection"?

Comment: Right, that might not have been very clear. So all users are in the "users" collections. Each user will get a role assigned within the "users" collection. One role is for a store, and the other role is for an employee. The idea is that the employee can find a job at a store, but the store should also be able to pick a new employee via a friend request. So two different roles need to be connected, I.e., the two users. So if they accept the friend request they can begin their work relationship. I'll look into the join table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you perhaps seen [fireship's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CipVwISumA) RE: fauna db? I think it covers what you want to do and how you can proceed.

Edit: There are many ways to implement this. Based on my understanding, perhaps you can have "Friends" and "Requests" arrays stored under a user document. That way you can differentiate between confirmed friends or a just request.

Example: When user1 initiates a friend request with user2, you store user1's ref under "Requests" of user2's document. When user2 confirms, you move user1's ref to the "Friends" array.

This is just a overly simplified idea and you may need to consider your options and the implications. You would need to plan and define the predicate in both roles so you would only see what is necessary.

Comment: This kind of clarifications must go under comments section instead of answers

Comment: I looked through the video. I believe it might be in the right direction, but when you follow someone, you don't have the acceptance first; like would you like to accept this request? Yes or No.

Comment: @AngelaAmarapala Sorry about that.. Will take note of it. Thanks